# Edge browser rendering huge fonts

Tags: windows-10-mobile, microsoft-edge

Here is an example with wikipedia page, and there are many other sites with the same issue. Is there a way to fix this annoying behavior?

[image]

Comment: Pinching in and out doesn't work for you?

Comment: Are you using Edge in desktop mode?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/huge-edge-font-size-after-anniversary-update-lumia/13b60ce9-66a7-4095-a486-609bb2f495fc solves the issue.

Comment: post it as an answer alongwith  some description.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following to set the text size back to normal:

- Go to `Settings > Ease of Access > More options > Text Scaling`. Move the slider to change the font size and see which settings works perfectly on the browser.
- Go to `Settings > Display > Size of text, apps and items on this display`. Move the slider and see which setting is perfect. (This setting will affect not the text but all your phone's UI)

Hope this helps. If it did, give me an upvote.